# How to delete row in html5 web sql

Tags: html

I tried below code please check where I am wrong

```
db.transaction(function(tx){

tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM People WHERE id = ?",[myid]);

    });


}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Web SQL? [It's already deprecated](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated), and [Firefox and IE do not support it](http://caniuse.com/sql-storage).

Comment: I am checking with chrome

Comment: works on me, maybe you need to omit `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` not `"`.

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM People WHERE id = ?',[myid]);
});
```

Comment: it doesn't matter either you use single quote or double quote.